# Git - Git using my user folder as repository

Tags: git, repository, directory, home-directory

**Git** is using my **home-user folder as repository.**
Every time I open **git gui** I can see every file under C:\Users\Mitcoc\
Is this normal? If is it, how I can disable it without unistalling git?

Edit: Git installed by visual studio if that helps.

Comment: delete the `.git` folder in your home folder if exists. a tip: try to learn git without involving ides

Comment: It passed through my mind but i kinda afraid to do it because last time i used Git(through Visual Studio Code) I accidentally deleted everything under my home folder. (BTW everytime someone installs git ,automatically is creating a repository under home folder?)

Comment: i can't answer you about that because i don't use ms's stuff. every single tool i tried pissed me off at least once. as i said, use cli directly. don't rely on ide. they oftenly do wrapping more than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git creates a directory .git in the directory where git is initialized. You can remove the .git/ directory to remove it from git control. There may also be a .gitignore file outside of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my first installation that was by default installed to my personal user folder. 
I found out if I click on the Git installation package (say, Git-2.16.1-64-bit.exe), and install it as an administrator to the target PC, then it will install it at C:\Program Files\Git folder.   And my VS Code can find it easier.

Comment: The OP's issue is that he has a **repository** in his home folder, not that git is installed there.